# How to extract PGS subtitle from m2ts using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Right now I'm mapping only the sub stream into an mkv and then using mkvextract to extract the pgs (.sup) file itself but is there a way to do that directly from ffmpeg? When I tried this command specifically `ffmpeg -i 00008.m2ts -c:s copy "08.sup"` ffmpeg complained that it was "Unable to find a suitable output format for 08.sup". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need a map subtitle stream at first, for example (subtitle track #8):

```
ffmpeg -i 00008.m2ts -map 0:8 -c:s copy "08.sup"
```